# What's wrong with this quest for initial velocity?

Tags: physics, projectile-motion

If I could borrow your time for a beginner question -- what is the problem with the computation [image: here]?

The problem is looking for the initial velocity of the projectile launched at an elevation of 1 meter with an angle of 45 degrees. The target range is 8 meters and elevated 3 meters.

The initial velocity is supposedly 10.22 m/s. But something went wrong in the middle.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only a small mistake: the sign of $g$. Let's look at the quation that you have defined:
$$
y=y_0 + v_0 \sin{\theta} t - \frac{1}{2}gt^2
$$
It seems like $y$ is the coordinate that grows upwards, and if $g>0$, this is the equation of a falling object (when $t$ is large, the $y$-coordinate becomes more and more negative). But for some reason, there's also
$$
g = -9.8~\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}^2}
$$
In this case, the object would go up indefinitely!

So as a conclusion, just switch the sign of $g$ and it's all good.

Comment: Hi, thank you @Matti for the quick answer. The sign of *g* is definitely one of the things that confuse me most of the time. Is there a rule that determines when I should use a negative or positive *g*? Would it be the same case if `y0 = 0?`?

Comment: Remember that it's not only the sign of $g$, but it's about the interplay of the equation of motion **and** the sign of the individual components. Always when you're thinking about the sign of any term, consistency is the most imporant thing. In other words, is the sign consistent with all the other things in the problem?

Comment: Duly noted. But from the example above as I'm still trying to wrap my head around it -- what made the *g* to be positive in this case? Thanks!